# Emacs has replaced all special characters with code

Tags: character-encoding

Somehow Emacs has replaced all my accented vowels with `\303\` and similar codes across all my orgmode files. It's a nightmare. How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: That usually happens when the coding system is "wrong": e.g, if you enter accented chars into a buffer which is saved with a UTF-8 coding system and then try to open the file wth e.g. a latin-1 coding system, that's what will happen.

Comment: How do I set the LF coding system globally? I may have changed it accidentally. I see below in the buffer LF RAW-TEXT.

Comment: Try clicking on `Options/Multilingual Environment/Set Language Environment/Default` and see if that cures it.

Comment: I tried but didn't work. I still see LF No CONVERSTION below :(( The only thing that works is adding "-*- coding: utf-8 -*-" on top of the buffer. Interestingly this happens only in one buffer.

Comment: I thought you said it was "across all my orgmode files", but now it's only one buffer? Which is it?

Comment: Be sure you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`, before reporting a problem. If you don't see the problem when you do that then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: This has been fixed. I had this character ^@ inside the buffer and was interfering!